# Android SQLite collate/order by utf8

Tags: android, sqlite

I have following items in SQLite table on Android (table tab has 1 column - 'name' text)

```
Beta
Work
Úpal
User
```

If I have these items in SQL Server with collation for Slovak language, and `select * from tab order by name`, it correctly outputs item sorted as:

```
Beta
User
Úpal
Work
```

In Slovak language, U with accent - Ú should be sorted after U.

In SQLite on Android, it outputs them in this order:

```
Beta
User
Work
Úpal
```

I understand what's going on, SQLite is possibly comparing the characters using the character code, and Ú is after W that way.

What can I do to make it sort my way? Is it even possible? 
[SQLite docs on COLLATION](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#collation) state that basically all collations are variants of binary comparison and do compare string data using memcmp(), regardless of text encoding.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite's C API allows to install [new collation sequences](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_collation.html).
These functions are not exposed by the Android API, but at least it installs two additional collations:

> In addition to SQLite's default `BINARY` collator, Android supplies two more, `LOCALIZED`, which changes with the system's current locale, and `UNICODE`, which is the Unicode Collation Algorithm and not tailored to the current locale.