# How make a query in Android SqlLite return in Latin order

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a query in my app android as below

```
SELECT N.NOME AS NUTRIENTE FROM NUTRIENTES WHERE CODNUTRIENTE IN (" + nutrientes + ") ORDER BY  N.NOME COLLATE NOCASE
```

it return result

```
Cálcio
ED Suinos
Fibra Bruta
Fósforo
Gordura
Lisina
Metionina
Proteina
Sódio´
Ácido
Triptofano
```

But it should return in correct order as

```
Ácido
Cálcio
ED Suinos
Fibra Bruta
Fósforo
Gordura
Lisina
Metionina
Proteina
Sódio
Triptofano
```

Anyone could help me or give a direction or a document to read, I searched for a answer in sqlite ofical site but I not found anything.
I create database as

public class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
  private static Context context;


  public static final String TABLE_NUTRIENTES = "NUTRIENTES";

  public static final String CREATE_TABLE_NUTRIENTES = "CREATE TABLE NUTRIENTES ( "
          + " CODNUTRIENTE   INTEGER primary key autoincrement, "
          + " NOME           VARCHAR(25) , "
          + " CODUNIDADE     INTEGER, "
          + " COMENTARIO     VARCHAR(1000) , "
          + " MULTIPLICADOR  REAL, "
          + " VISIVEL        INTEGER, "
          + " TRAVADO        INTEGER, "
          + " FOREIGN KEY (CODUNIDADE) REFERENCES UNIDADES (CODUNIDADE) ON UPDATE CASCADE "
          + "   ); ";

  private static String DATABASE_NAME = ((Config)Config.getInstance(context)).getValue("BancoDeDados") + ".db";
  private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;


  public MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.context=context;
  }

  public MySQLiteHelper(Context context, String nomeBanco) {
      super(context, nomeBanco + ".db", null, DATABASE_VERSION);
      this.context=context;
  }

@Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    if (!database.isReadOnly()) {
          database.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;");
    }
    criaTabelas(database);


    preencheNutrientes(database);


  }

  @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    Log.w(MySQLiteHelper.class.getName(),
        "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
            + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");


    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NUTRIENTES);


    onCreate(db);
  }

  public void criaTabelas(SQLiteDatabase database) {

    database.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_NUTRIENTES);

  }


  public void preencheNutrientes(SQLiteDatabase database) {
      List<String[]> valueslist = Util.readCsv(context,"nutrientes.csv");

      for(String[] dados: valueslist){  
            ContentValues insertValues = new ContentValues();
            insertValues.put("CODNUTRIENTE",dados[0]);
            insertValues.put("NOME",dados[1]);
            insertValues.put("CODUNIDADE",dados[3]);
            insertValues.put("COMENTARIO",dados[2]);
            insertValues.put("MULTIPLICADOR",dados[4]);
            insertValues.put("VISIVEL",dados[5]);
            insertValues.put("TRAVADO",dados[6]);
            database.insert("NUTRIENTES", null, insertValues);
     }
  }


@SuppressLint("Override")
public static String getDatabaseName() {
    return DATABASE_NAME;
}
@Override
public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    if (!db.isReadOnly()) {
        db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;");
    }
    super.onOpen(db);
}

public static void changeDatabase(String nomeBD) {
    DATABASE_NAME = nomeBD + ".db";
}
```

}

Comment: According to [this bit](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_collation.html) of the docs, `COLLATE NOCASE` won't work with UTF. According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14467806/android-sqlite-collate-order-by-utf8) although the SQLite API allows you to define your own collation, the Android wrapper doesn't, but does offer a Unicode collation that might do what you want.

Comment: sqlite doesnt supprt the other languages afaik, you might think of saving your strings into another column with all lower case letters, and then sort according to the lowercase.

Comment: "Solved", I made another column without graphic accents

Comment: @Heberfa Have you tried my answer? It is not a good design solution to duplicate information just to order a column.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to give you an answer but I found that I had the same problem. Anyway, I just found the solution :).

**You only need to add `COLLATE LOCALIZED`** in the definition of your table. Use `VARCHAR(25) COLLATE LOCALIZED` or `TEXT COLLATE LOCALIZED` for `NOME`.

Remember that you need to re create your database to apply this change or write the corresponding code in `onUpgrade` function.

By doing this, you will not need to use `COLLATE` in the `SELECT` statement.